# Matching two columns from different tables - MySQL PHP

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in mysql

- table 1 is vehicles, has records of all vehicles
- table 2 is contributions, has records of daily contributions from the vehicles

I have a column in both tables called `regno`

I want a query that will display `vehicle` `regno` that is not in `contributions`

What I tried:

```sql
SELECT vehicles.regno FROM vehicles,contributions
WHERE vehicles.regno<>contributions.regno
ORDER BY vehicles.regno;
```

Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: You welcome.. anytime :)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT regno FROM vehicles
WHERE regno NOT IN (SELECT regno FROM contributions);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT V.regno FROM vehicles AS V
LEFT JOIN contributions AS C
ON (V.regno = C.regno)
WHERE C.regno IS NULL;
```

Comment: @dannjoroge  Theoretically the two queries between ```join``` and ```where in ``` are equivalent. I think it's just poor implementation of the MySQL query optimizer that causes JOIN to be more efficient than WHERE IN.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to get the results:

```sql
SELECT v.regno
FROM vehicles v

LEFT JOIN contributions c ON c.regno = v.regno -- A LEFT JOIN produces a set of records which matches every entry in the left table (user) regardless of any matching entry in the right table

WHERE c.regno IS NULL -- This will filter out results where right table entry is not available
ORDER BY vehicles.regno;
```